# Unsure on how to improve question

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

Earlier today, I asked a question on how to enable [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) headers on a CRM365 on-premises installation (*[Enable CORS on CRM365 (on-premises)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73525816/enable-cors-on-crm365-on-premises)*).

Maybe I missed something obvious, but unfortunately I don't understand which additional details I should add to my question. I also don't understand why people downvoted my question and why it eventually was closed.

It's just that I would like my Microsoft Dynamics CRM 365 server which is installed on-premises sent the correct CORS headers so that I can use it for data queries from another web site.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: While we allow a lot of latitude for extended discussion in the comments on Meta, these comments were really getting out of hand, especially considering that *no one* had posted an answer yet. As such, I've [archived the comments in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247726/discussion-on-question-by-toms-unsure-on-how-to-improve-question). **Please post an answer if you have an opinion to share**; that's how Meta works. It doesn't have to be the perfect answer; it doesn't have to address all aspects of the question. Most of what was posted as comments here should have been answers.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't see this until after all of the initial commentary, but the archived comments make it look like the concerns were mostly centered on

1. the perception of inadequate preliminary research
2. the perception of inadequate detail about the problem.

One approach would be to edit your question to try to incorporate more information about those elements. If that fails, I think your approach of asking another question is appropriate, and it appears to have led (directly or indirectly) to a workable solution.